# how can i make shared embedded framework to work in ios7

Tags: ios7, ios8, ios-frameworks

I planned to create a shared embedded framework to share the code between more than one target. I heard that shared embedded frameworsk are an ios8 new feature. Since how what can i do to make that shared embedded framework to make it work on ios7?. I want to support both ios8 and ios7.

Any help that might be appreciate